# Grails: store domain classes in user session

Tags: grails

I want to create a simple web album with grails where the user need to have a profile, albums and pictures. I know the one to one and many to many relationship but that is not the problem, the problem is that i want to automatically add the profile, album and picture classes to the requested user session immediately they are logged in. I am using grails 2.2.1.
Please i really need your help, thank you for you time.

Comment: Why? Might help to know the underlying problem.

Comment: Storing domain classes in the session may cause problems with hibernate session.

Comment: but how it's related to user session? why session?

Comment: @SergioMichels Am so sorry for your time, what i actually need is to validate a user which i have already done but the problem is that i want a user to be attached to their profile, albums and pictures. Example James' profile, albums and pictures. how will i connect those domain classes (Profile, album and picture) with the user session. Thanks for your time.